# Creating Workflow -> Error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, error, custom-actions

When I try to create a new WF in my Sharepoint Designer I get following error:

> The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that
>   does not exist. Some actions will not be avaliable. The assembly
>   strong name is "Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkFlowActions,
>   Version=14.0.0.0,Cultureneutral,PublickeyToke=

Does any on know how to fix this problem?

Comment: This is happening when the workflow is run?  or is it occuring on the deployment of the workflow?

Comment: This occurs during creating a new workflow in workflow designer.

Comment: Did you ever solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I will sometimes get this prompt when SharePoint Designer 2010 is not running with administrative credentials for the local computer. I haven't been able to pin down anything more specific than that, but try launching it by right click on the icon and choosing "Run as administrator"